# VBA code to split quantity value given a certain threshold

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create an automated task to split quantity values to subsequent rows if the amount reaches a certain threshold. For example I set the max limit to 600 and I want the residual values to be printed in the rows below until the original value has been split. If value is below the threshold, then it's left as is. Below is the sample data that I want to achieve. Thank you!

[image]

```
Sub SplitNumbers()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim newCell As Range
    Dim threshold As Double
    
    ' Set the worksheet and threshold value
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' 
    threshold = 600
    
    ' Loop through each cell in a specific column 
    For Each cell In ws.Range("C1:C" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        If cell.Value > threshold Then
            ' Insert a new row below the current row
            cell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            
            ' Put the threshold value in the current cell
            cell.Value = threshold
            
            ' Put the residual value in the cell below
            Set newCell = cell.Offset(1, 0)
            newCell.Value = cell.Value - threshold
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use arrays to read the data, manipulate within the arrays and then read it back to the worksheet, as handling large sizes of data with the worksheet tends to take a lot of time, especially if you need to insert a lot rows.

See code below (and comments in it):

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitNumbers()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim newCell As Range
Dim threshold As Double, CurrentValueLeftover As Double
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, ArrIndex As Long, Col As Long

Dim TempArr As Variant
Dim NewDataArr As Variant


' Set the worksheet and threshold value
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
threshold = 600

With ws
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    TempArr = .Range("A1:C" & LastRow).Value ' read entire range values to 2-D arrays
End With

ReDim NewDataArr(1 To 10 * UBound(TempArr, 1), 1 To UBound(TempArr, 2))
ArrIndex = 0

' --- loop through array --> much quicker ---
For i = 1 To UBound(TempArr, 1)
    CurrentValueLeftover = TempArr(i, 3) ' initialize value
    
    ' while value > threshold --> add more array rows
    While CurrentValueLeftover > threshold
        CurrentValueLeftover = CurrentValueLeftover - threshold
        
        ArrIndex = ArrIndex + 1
        
        NewDataArr(ArrIndex, 1) = TempArr(i, 1)
        NewDataArr(ArrIndex, 2) = TempArr(i, 2)
        NewDataArr(ArrIndex, 3) = threshold
    Wend
        
    ' last row is the reminder of the Value (or first value if < threshold)
    ArrIndex = ArrIndex + 1
    
    NewDataArr(ArrIndex, 1) = TempArr(i, 1)
    NewDataArr(ArrIndex, 2) = TempArr(i, 2)
    NewDataArr(ArrIndex, 3) = CurrentValueLeftover

Next i

' ~~~ Nice TRICK to redim first Dimension of 2-D array ~~~
If ArrIndex > 0 Then
    TempArr = NewDataArr
    ReDim NewDataArr(1 To ArrIndex, 1 To UBound(NewDataArr, 2))
    For i = 1 To ArrIndex
        For Col = 1 To UBound(NewDataArr, 2)
            NewDataArr(i, Col) = TempArr(i, Col)
        Next Col
    Next i
End If

' paste entire 2-D array to worksheet at once
ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(NewDataArr, 1), UBound(NewDataArr, 2)).Value = NewDataArr
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Batching the rows inserts:

```vb
Sub SplitNumbers()
    Const LIMIT As Long = 600
    Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range, amt, rep, i As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set c = ws.Range("A1")
    
    Application.Screenupdating = False
    Do While Len(c.Value) > 0
        amt = c.Offset(0, 2).Value
        rep = Application.Ceiling(amt / LIMIT, 1) 'total rows?
        If rep > 1 Then                           'need new rows?
            c.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rep - 1).EntireRow.Insert
            c.Resize(rep, 2).Value = c.Resize(1, 2).Value  'Fill Cols A, B
            c.Offset(0, 2).Resize(rep - 1).Value = LIMIT
            c.Offset(rep - 1, 2).Value = amt - ((rep - 1) * LIMIT) 'remainder
        End If
        Set c = c.Offset(rep)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very close to working. The revised version follows your logic as closely as possible, making it easier for future maintenance. Of course, implementing it with arrays will improve efficiency.

Here are some key points:

- Make sure to update `cell.Value = threshold` after setting newCell.Value, otherwise newCell will have a value of zero.
- A nested loop is needed to handle the splitting.
- Consider changing `For Each` to a `For` loop, as the `ws.Range("C1:C" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)` is altered after inserting a new row. A `For Each` loop can result in unnecessary extra iterations.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SplitNumbers()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim newCell As Range
    Dim threshold As Double
    ' Set the worksheet and threshold value
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '
    threshold = 600
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Loop through each cell in a specific column
    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        Set cell = ws.Cells(i, "C")
        Debug.Print cell.Address
        Do While cell.Value > threshold
            ' Insert a new row below the current row
            cell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            ' Put the residual value in the cell below
            Set newCell = cell.Offset(1, 0)
            newCell.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 2).Value = cell.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 2).Value
            newCell.Value = cell.Value - threshold
            ' Put the threshold value in the current cell
            cell.Value = threshold
            Set cell = newCell
        Loop
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code

1. First put the residual values to the new row and then subtract Threshold value.
2. Missing the new row other data.

**Correction**

Change code within `If` statement

```
            
            ' Insert a new row below the current row
            cell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            Set newCell = cell.Offset(1, 0)
            ' Put the residual value in the cell below
            newCell.Value = cell.Value - threshold       'moved
            newCell.Offset(0, -1) = cell.Offset(0, -1)   'inserted
            newCell.Offset(0, -2) = cell.Offset(0, -2)   'inserted 
            
            ' Put the threshold value in the current cell
            cell.Value = threshold
```